# If else button clicked not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something when a button is clicked, sample code below.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y5s4um5/)

```
$(":button").click(function() {
   if ($(this).prop("id") == "update") {
        alert("Update clicked");
    }
    else {
        alert("Add clicked");   
    }
});
```

This works in fiddle, but strangely does not work on my localhost.

I get an error (`Uncaught SyntaxError: UnExpected token Illegal`) at this line:

```
if ($(this).prop("id") == "update") {
```

I'm using jQuery 1.10.0.

Any idea why?

Comment: Which jquery version You are using ? .The prop was introduced  jQuery 1.6 and above

Comment: I would say its the version.. use `.attr`

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.10.0

Comment: in fiddle yes, but on local too?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any script error, go to the console and check if you had any javascript error.

Comment: Yes on local the version is 1.10.0. And the error that i posted above is while debugging in firefox

Comment: I tried using .attr instead of .prop, still get the same error.

Comment: and if you do only an alert on click, without the if/else?

Comment: dude check the answer that i have posted.

Comment: @Robin your answer its just an other way to get the name... his example should be working... and also you used input for some reason...

Comment: ok just see my updated answer and tell if something is remainign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `this.id`:

```
$(":button").click(function () {
    if (this.id == "update") {
        alert("Update clicked");
    } else {
        alert("Add clicked");
    }
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/3cx8f5ow/)

Comment: I tried removing if else and put an alert. Now I get "Illegal character on alert!! Also I tried Robin's and ChipChocolate's code..nothing works..I'm updating fiddle shortly with my actual project code shortly.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: I still get the same error..SyntaxError.. I can't figure out what's the issue

Comment: please check if you have defined the <script type="text/javascript" src="your jquery file path here"></script> tag

Comment: Did you try using a newer version of jQuery? If not, try this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: please define the jquery file before defining your js file

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me. Please check this in your browser too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(":button").click(function(){
           if($(this).prop("id") == "update"){
                alert("Update clicked");
            }
            else {
                alert("Add clicked");   
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="update" type="button">UPDATE</button>
<button id="add" type="button">ADD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!! What I was doing is changing the js directly in target and doing a refresh, clearing cache and trying to load the page again..that's how I usually test my js changes..maybe that is why the error was thrown..I tried by building the war file again and it works this.id == update

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="update" data-type="update" />
```

in js write the following code

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("data-id") == "update") {
        alert("Update clicked");
    }
    else {
        alert("Add clicked");   
    }
 });
```

Or Try these things

```
$(this).attr('id');
or
$(this).get(0).id;
or
$(this)[0].id;
```

Comment: in html use data-type or data-whatevername = "update" and then search it by the .attr() method.